# slider to enter mobile number using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, events, slider

I am working on a UI tweak where I want to select mobile number using slider.
 user will select a digit between range 0 to 9 using slider.
on each selection user will press [space bar] or [esc] key to confirm selected number.
After confirmation the number should display in a textbox or label field.

As of now I am able to proceed till selecting a single number from slider.
can any one suggest on binding events to select phone number?

on this probably I want to bind event

```
$("#PhNumber").on("slidestop", function (e) {
     $("#output").html($("#PhNumber").val());
});
```

here is the fiddle I have tried :
http://jsfiddle.net/8hphL2jp/13/

And code snippet :

```js
$("#PhNumber").on("slidestop", function (e) {
    $("#output").html($("#PhNumber").val());
});

$("#PhNumber").on("focusin focusout", function (e) {
    if (e.type == "focusin") {
        $(this).on("change", function (e) {
            $("#change").html($("#PhNumber").val());
        });
    } else {
        $(this).off("change");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div data-role="page">
    <label for="PhNumber">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="range" name="PhNumber" id="PhNumber" value="0" min="0" max="9" />
    <div>Slidestop:<span id="output">---</span>
    </div>
    <div>Input:<span id="change">---</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're looking for something like this snippet. You can bind `keyup` to the document to determine when a key is pressed at that time you can check if any of the keys pressed match the keyCode you would like to listen for.

To keep the "---" at the start you can apply another if to test if the span contains "---" and if it does empty it before appending your numbers.

```js
$("#PhNumber").on("change", function (e) {
  $("#output").html($("#PhNumber").val());
});

$(document).on("keyup", function (e) {
    if($("#change").text() === "---"){
      $("#change").empty();
    } 
    
    if(e.keyCode === 32 || e.keyCode === 8){ 
      $("#change").append($("#PhNumber").val());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="page">
    <label for="PhNumber">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="range" name="PhNumber" id="PhNumber" value="0" min="0" max="9" />
    <div>Slidestop:<span id="output">---</span>
    </div>
    <div>Input:<span id="change">---</span>
    </div>
</div>
```